# DOM doesn't update when I make event changes in jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Basically, the component's operation is to change the screen and click on the menu button, which has the same event mentioned in the test: somaTabsChange

However, when I run the test, it fails to change the DOM with the new elements.

Basically, this is log i get:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of:
> Criar menu

Test

```
  it('should render the menu when save a modal', async () => {
    getPageManagerInfo();
    nock(env.SERVICE_URL)
      .persist()
      .post('/modules/cards/menu', {
        name: 'menus',
        icon: 'menus',
      })
      .reply(200, {
        moduleMenu: {
          pages: [],
          _id: '61d33fd3b922dd0011ddc024',
          icon: 'menus',
          name: 'menus',
          __v: 0,
        },
      });

    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    history.push('/manager/module/cards');

    const renderResult = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/manager/module/:id" exact>
          <PageManager />
        </Route>
      </Router>,
    );

    await changeTabs(renderResult, 'menus', 'menus');

    await callModalForm({
      render: renderResult,
      buttonLabel: 'Criar menu',
      buttonConfirmLabel: 'Salvar',
      events: async () => {
        await changeInput(renderResult, 'Nome', 'menus');
        await changeInput(renderResult, 'Ícone', 'menus');
      },
    });
    await callButton(renderResult, 'Fechar modal');
  });
```

Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SomaTab } from '@soma/react';

import { getModule } from 'services/ModuleService';
import Module from 'models/ModuleV2';

import LoaderFull from 'components/LoaderFull';
import ListPages from './container/ListPages';
import ListMenus from './container/ListMenus';
import { StyledTabs } from './styles';

const PageManager: React.FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [module, setModule] = useState<Module>();
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState<string>('pages');

  const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const result = await getModule(id);
    if (result.data) {
      setModule(result.data);
    } else {
      history.push('/404');
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <LoaderFull />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <StyledTabs value={tab} onSomaTabsChange={e => setTab(e.detail)}>
        <SomaTab value="pages">Páginas</SomaTab>
        <SomaTab aria-label="menus" value="menus">
          menus
        </SomaTab>
      </StyledTabs>
      {tab === 'pages' ? (
        <ListPages module={module!} onUpdate={getData} />
      ) : (
        <ListMenus module={module!} onUpdate={getData} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PageManager;
```